# Trouble with CSP while loading the Axios API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, content-security-policy

I am trying to load the Axios API in a NodeJS/Express/JavaScript environment. When I use the API I get an error that Axios is not defined, because my system won't load the script citing a Content Security Policy breach.

I installed Axios ver 1.6.1 using npm i.

I've tried the following script in my HTML file:

```
meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; script-src-elem 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net")
```

This did not work.

I tried the following code in the App.js file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) =\> {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only',
    "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net"
  );
  next();
});
```

Didn't help either.

This is the latest message I am getting:
Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I don't know what more I can do. Can someone please help?
Thanks.
Leon

I cleared the browser cache, checked for script conflicts, but they had no impact on the resulting error.